# How can I know that which apps are eating data usage in ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-environments

I don't know that how to find data usage of app.

Answer (score 0):

1. I found out that `iftop` is a nice option for data monitoring by specific interface.

   - You need to run the command with `sudo`.
   - Use the `-i` flag to choose specific interface.

   Example:

   ```
   sudo iftop -i <interface>
   ```

2.You can use `top` command to see all the running processes filtered by:
- PID - Process id.
- USER - user that running the process.
- %CPU - the cpu percent the app is using.

3. You can view these topics for "larger" data usage apps on Ubuntu:

   - https://superuser.com/questions/615958/how-to-track-internet-usage-upload-download-on-linux
   - https://www.tecmint.com/linux-network-bandwidth-monitoring-tools/

Comment: asilbek - if this answer is helpful for you, please accept her, if its not what you looking for or having issues with operating the "iftop" service please comment so we can solve that issue together.